# Debug Assertion Failed in fwrite.cpp

Tags: c++, c, exception, fopen, fwrite

Sorry in advance for any lack of knowledge but im a C# developer attempting to look at a C problem.

A customer installed a piece of software on a new machine which is working on other machines without any issues.

They receive the error:

```
Debug Asertion Failed!

Program: C:\MyDirectory\MyDll.dll
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\studio\fwrite.cpp
Line: 33

Expression: stream != nullptr
```

The FOpen in question is being opened with w+ rights but is obviously failing which is why the FClose is throwing this exception. I know there should be a null check on the pointer before attempting an FClose but ill fix that later.

The FOpen just specifies the file name so should be created in the current working directory.

Because the FOpen is failing and the attempt is with w+ (which grants read, write and create file privilege), am i correct to assume that the only reason it can fail is due to invalid privileges at the operating system level for the program to create files?

I dont currently have access to the machine to have a look. Trying to accumulate possible issues before i get access.

Comment: There should be a null check immediately after `fopen`. Or at least before fist use of it in call to `fwrite` or whatever.

Comment: 'C' and 'C++' are two different languages, pick one and remove the other tag.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can help you, some random error message (that we cannot reproduce) is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things can make an `fopen` fail, so its hard to say. Insufficient privileges are, however, a quite common reason. To find out the real reason, you could use the error message provided by the operating system, which you can get as follows:

```
#include <errno.h>
....
char* filename = "example.txt";
fp = fopen (filename,"w+");
if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error opening %s: %s", filename, strerror(errno));
      return;
}
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Well if my original fopen is going to fail why would that one succeed!! But ya ill just popup the error as a messgebox.

Comment: Did you find out the reason?

Comment: It will take a while to get the version to the customer to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check this would have been - print the `errno`.

How we usually do this? whenever we use `fopen` immediately after it we check the value returned by it. In case of `NULL` we can check the `errno`. (The link here has a section example which shows that also).

When fopen fails it sets the `errno` to indicate the error. And the reason may be anything from access permission to that the file doesn't exist.

[***Here***](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) there is some list of reasons why `fopen` can fail. (You asked for the reason of the failing)